# Run electron shows that GPU process exited unexpectedly

Tags: node.js, angular, electron, gpu, electron-builder

I create an electron app. I try to run it with "npm run start:electron"

in package.json:
"start:electron": "npx electron dist/electron/main.js",

and the errors are:
npx electron dist/electron/main.js

[15452:0608/152339.809:ERROR:gpu_process_host.cc(979)] GPU process exited unexpectedly: exit_code=-1073741659
[15452:0608/152339.888:ERROR:gpu_process_host.cc(979)] GPU process exited unexpectedly: exit_code=-1073741659
[15452:0608/152339.967:ERROR:gpu_process_host.cc(979)] GPU process exited unexpectedly: exit_code=-1073741659
[15452:0608/152340.046:ERROR:gpu_process_host.cc(979)] GPU process exited unexpectedly: exit_code=-1073741659
[15452:0608/152340.125:ERROR:gpu_process_host.cc(979)] GPU process exited unexpectedly: exit_code=-1073741659
[15452:0608/152340.216:ERROR:gpu_process_host.cc(979)] GPU process exited unexpectedly: exit_code=-1073741659
[15452:0608/152340.781:ERROR:gpu_process_host.cc(979)] GPU process exited unexpectedly: exit_code=-1073741659
[15452:0608/152340.860:ERROR:gpu_process_host.cc(979)] GPU process exited unexpectedly: exit_code=-1073741659
[15452:0608/152340.939:ERROR:gpu_process_host.cc(979)] GPU process exited unexpectedly: exit_code=-1073741659
[15452:0608/152340.939:FATAL:gpu_data_manager_impl_private.cc(448)] GPU process isn't usable. Goodbye.

What happen to the GPU process?

Comment: which OS are you using?